# List the target directories of a shortcut folder in a main folder

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, shortcut, target

Is there a python code to list the target directories of a shortcut folder? What I am trying to do is to list all the folders and their sub-folders in a target directory and apparently most of the folders in this main folder are shortcut folders.

When I run the python program below it skips all the shortcut folders.

```
import os

main_folder_path = r"mainfolder"

for path, directory, files in os.walk(main_folder_path):
    print(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'C:/git/my_docs/'

os.listdir(path)
```

Output:

```
['.spyproject',
 'commands',
 'files.csv',
 'mappings.csv',
 'script.py',
 'theexchange-data-dynamics-library-master']
```

This should do the trick. It will list all of the underlying files in a directory in the form of a list.

Comment: Am trying to get the full path of all directories including the shortcut directories in this folder. how do i do this in python.